# UserDefaults value seems to be reset every few runs of the app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have some popup alerts that I want to come up ONLY when it is a user's very first time in the app. As an example, I have this alert:

```
func showTip() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun") {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Welcome! Go ahead and create a chat room", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
        })
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
    }
}
```

That should come up, as I said, only on the very first run of the app. I set the user defaults values in AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultValues = ["firstRun" : true]
    userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

However the popup is showing frequently. I haven't noticed any sort of pattern, and it doesn't come up every single run, but every few times I run the app the alert comes up.

Is there any way I can make it so after the first time the alert comes up, it's disabled entirely for that user?

Comment: Unrelated but there is no reason to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to set the value in `UserDefaults`. Besides, the code is already on the main queue.

Comment: Ok, I'll get rid of that - thanks

Comment: Don't register the key / value pair right before retrieving the value in the same function, do it earlier for example in `applicationWillFinishLaunching`

Comment: Also, it looks like you're setting "firstRun" to true every time `showTip` is called. Thus, `if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun")` is always going to be true.

Comment: @toddg No it does not. `register` sets the default value only if the key does not exist in the database otherwise it's ignored.

Comment: @vadian So just move the 3 lines before the `if` to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: @vadian my mistake

Comment: Yes, most likely that  solves the problem.

Comment: Ok, I think it will be hard to test this one because the alert only came up once in a while, so I'll have to re-run the app a bunch of times and see if it holds. That solution makes sense though - doesn't it go along with what @toddg was saying? Removing registering the value from the function and putting in in App Delegate ensures that I'm not resetting the value every time?

Comment: `register(defaults:)` doesn't reset anything. It only provides a fallback value if there isn't an explicit value stored for the key. You should be able call `register(defaults:)` all over your app without causing an issue. Of course it only makes sense to call it once during app startup.

Comment: Ok - just trying to understand what was causing the alert to pop up randomly when those lines were in the function. Hopefully this fixes it but it'd be interesting to know why. Regardless from now on I'll keep this is mind and always set user defaults values in App Delegate.

Comment: @Leif it is generally not necessary to call `synchronise` as defaults are persisted automatically as stated in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: @KingTim you can simplify things if you invert your logic `defaults.bool(forKey:"hasRun")` will return false if the value is false or there is no value. You can then set `defaults.setBool(true, forKey:"hasRun")` and avoid the whole register defaults thing.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem is coming up again. I made the suggested changes but the alert still comes up every few runs of the app. I've edited my question to show the code that I have now.